# Expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list when loading a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, file

This is my code:
import easygui

```
while True:
    try:
        print('Select your file')
        proxyfile = easygui.fileopenbox('', 'Select your file')
        proxylines = proxyfile.splitlines()
        proxylinesamount = len(open(proxylines).readlines())
        break

    except (TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
        print(f'Error. File isn\'t valid. Reason: {e}')
        continue
```

For some reason it returns the following error:

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

I understand that this is a TypeError but I simply can't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `proxylines` is a list and you're trying to open it as a file.

Comment: what was the purpose of proxyfile.splitlines()?

Comment: @PApostol any idea on how I can convert it to a string?

Comment: @llamaCaraDara oops i forgot to remove that part. It has another purpose later on in the script.

Comment: it looks like you want to use len(open(proxyfile).readlines()). from what i'm reading in easygui fileopenbox returns a file path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you wanted this:

```
import easygui

while True:
    try:
        print('Select your file')
        proxy_file = easygui.fileopenbox('', 'Select your file')  # Type: str
        with open(proxy_file, 'r') as fh:
            proxy_lines = list(fh)
            proxy_lines_amount = len(proxy_lines)
        break  # i'm not sure if while True and break are viable here

    except (TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
        print(f'Error. File isn\'t valid. Reason: {e}')
        continue
```

Comment: I think `list(fh)` is more usually done as `fh.readlines()`

Comment: @Barmar sure thing! However I prefer it this way. don't... beat me.. please?

Comment: No problem, but consider yourself on notice :)